# What is the hex code console gives when creating object of a class in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

When I create an object of the class in ruby, the console returns a Hex code. What is the significance of this hex code?

apple = Fruits.new
=> #Fruits:0x00005569446a55d8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're running this in irb, or some sort of interactive console. In this scenario `inspect` is used to display a representation of `apple`. If you haven't defined your own `inspect` in the `Fruits` class, then it's inherited from `Object`.

> #### [inspect → string](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Object.html#method-i-inspect)
>
> Returns a string containing a human-readable representation of *obj*.
> The default [`inspect`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Object.html#method-i-inspect) shows the object's class name, an encoding
> of its memory address, and a list of the instance variables and their
> values (by calling [`inspect`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Object.html#method-i-inspect) on each of them). User defined
> classes should override this method to provide a better representation
> of *obj*. When overriding this method, it should return a string whose
> encoding is compatible with the default external encoding.
>
> ```
> [ 1, 2, 3..4, 'five' ].inspect   #=> "[1, 2, 3..4, \"five\"]"
> Time.new.inspect                 #=> "2008-03-08 19:43:39 +0900"
>
> class Foo
> end
> Foo.new.inspect                  #=> "#<Foo:0x0300c868>"
>
> class Bar
>   def initialize
>     @bar = 1
>   end
> end
> Bar.new.inspect                  #=> "#<Bar:0x0300c868 @bar=1>"
> ```

Comment: yes, I am using IRB, the Hex code you get when you create object like this #=> "#<Foo:0x0300c868>". what is the significance of this, is this object_id or something else?

Comment: Quote from [the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Object.html#method-i-inspect): _Returns a string containing a human-readable representation of obj. The default inspect shows the object's class name, an encoding of its memory address, and a list of the instance variables and their values (by calling inspect on each of them). User defined classes should override this method to provide a better representation of obj._

Comment: @GauravSharma It's an encoding of its memory addresses. Not that useful if you're a developer working in Ruby. However I assume it's quite useful if you're a C developer working on the Ruby-core, or developing native Ruby Gems written in C.